# Github issue search in command line

Tags: git, github, command-line

I am trying to search for issues with keywords in github.
I want to achieve this from command line.

I have already tried ghi ([`stephencelis/ghi`: GitHub Issues on the command line](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi)) --> the installation doesn't work.
Could you please suggest any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2022: [`gh` 2.7.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.7.0) comes with [`gh search issues`](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/5334)

> Adds the `search issues` and `search prs` command.
>
> The `search issues` command includes a `--include-prs` flag that allows for including pull requests in the search results.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7969779/159436553-7ff52845-7c89-42f6-9b5b-588d7c44e4e9.png -- Screen Shot 2022-03-22 at 10 13 15 AM]

---

Update 2020: The [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/) is now 1.0 [and available](https://github.blog/2020-09-17-github-cli-1-0-is-now-available/).
As noted in [Alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823226/alireza)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63945790/6309), it can list issue through the [`gh issue list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_list) command.

If the keyword is a label, you can use `gh issue list -l xxx` to filter by label.
If not, grepping the title is a possible workaround.

From [GH 1.8.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.8.0)

> The new `issue/pr list --search` flag enables searching issues and pull requests using keywords.
>
> In addition to searching by words that may appear in the contents of issues or pull requests, you can use any GitHub search syntax for more specific matching and to change the order of the results.
>
> For example:
>
> - `gh issue list --state closed --search "crash in:title"` - closed issues that contain "crash" in their title
> - `gh issue list --search "no:assignee"` - open issues without an assignee
> - `gh issue list -l "bug" --search "sort:interactions-desc"` - bug threads that have the most interactions
> - `gh pr list --search "review-requested:@me"` - pull requests where your review was requested
> - `gh pr list --state merged --search "merged:>=2021-03-30"` - pull requests merged after a certain date

---

2017: You can [search issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) with [GitHub Search APOI](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) using the command-line [`curl` (see this tutorial)](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960)

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token my_token' 'https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=akeyword+repo:auser/arepo'
```

This is a workaround, while you can debug why a ruby/rail program like [`stephencelis/ghi`](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi) does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the official [Github CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) and you can add an issue and view them with the below command after installing `gh` and navigate to your project directory:

```
$ gh issue list | grep `search term`
```